# Swift Images to Cache

Tags: swift, image, caching

I am parsing data and checking if an image is in cache.  If yes, set it, if not set it to default and send it to cache.

The part that sends it to cache keeps giving nil ???

Any help would be appreciated

Pic_STR = "https://myserver/Pictures/" + Pic + ".jpg"
                let url = URL(string: Pic_STR)

```
            if let imageFromCache = imageCache.object(forKey: Pic_STR as AnyObject) as? UIImage {
                data.photo = imageFromCache
                return
            } else {
                data.photo = UIImage(named: "Default")
                let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, AnyObject>()
                URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
                    guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }

                        let imageToCache = UIImage(data: data)
                        imageCache.setObject(imageToCache!, forKey: self.Pic_STR as NSString)
                        //self.image = imageToCache

                    }.resume()
            }
```

Comment: you need to declare your `imageCache` object as a property of your view controller or declare it as property of a singleton.

Comment: Yes, declaring the object got rid of the error, but the code is still not workig, ATS failed system trust, ATS failed system trust, TIC SSL Trust Error

Comment: try setting  NSAllowsArbitraryLoads in your info plist

Comment: Setting the NSAllowArbitraryLoads did not work

Answer (score 0):

After much experiminting I finally found a solution.  I am sure it could be improved, but it works.  I would prefer to use an extension, but can't figure out how.

```
struct imageData {
    let image: UIImage?
    let name: String?
}

var newImage = UIImage()
var myImages = [imageData]()


   let imageString= "https://myserver/Pictures/" + Pic + ".jpg"
            let imageURL = URL(string: imageString)

            CON2 = false

            for pics in myImages {
                if pics.name == Pic {
                    data.photo = pics.image
                    CON2 = true
                }
            }

            if CON2 == false {
                let data2 = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL!)

                if let imageData = data2 {
                    newImage = UIImage(data: imageData)!
                }

                let newData = imageData(image: newImage, name: Pic) as imageData
                myImages += [newData]
                data.photo = newImage
            }
```